# iPad Full Screen Modal View over TabBarController?

Tags: ios, view, modal-dialog, tabbarcontroller

On a TabBar-based application on the iPad, is there a way to present a modal on top of it in "FullScreen"?

I have a LANDSCAPE ONLY APP (if that makes a difference) and the item I want to currently present modally I would like to present full screen, filling the entire screen just to clarify. I can present it in "PageSheet" fine, and "FormSheet" is all right, after a few button adjustments on the modal view nib, but once I try "FullScreen", the background goes white (TabBar still there, though), and if I retry hitting the button (without restarting the simulator), it won't respond.

The view where the button is located to present the modal view is CountryViewController.m and has the action:

```
-(IBAction) showNewModal:(id)sender {
modalContent.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
modalContent.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentModalViewController:modalContent animated:YES];
}
```

This code works fine without the TabBar, I've realized. I've looked for hours for something to add to this code or even in the AppDelegate.h and .m files but so far, it's either unresponsive (oddly enough without showing an error) or the aforementioned white space.

Comment: is your problem that modal view is not presenting in full screen with tab bar controller?

Comment: I'm trying to post a new modal view over the tab bar controller, NOT make a modal tab bar controller. This modal view is completely separate from the tab bar.

Answer (score 6):

in my experience the problem comes from presenting the modal from the wrong controller.

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:modalContent animated:YES];
```

should work

If you work with iOS 4 a (maybe) beter options is to use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentModalViewController:modalContent animated:YES];
```

Comment: +1 for the second suggestion. Could not get the first one to work.