# Is it possible to hide the tab bar on iOS apps?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

In designing a concept that focusses on conferences. My lay-out makes use of the [Tab Bar](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/tab-bars/). However, not on all screens a tab bar should be visible. This is

- Whenever you get a 'succes' overlay layer over the current screen (the tab bar may be visible, but blocked by the overlay)
- Regular screen with focus on a certain action/content. To maintain focus the tab bar should be hidden. Once you press the '< back' button in the menu, you'll be returned to a default page that got that tab bar and let's you navigate.

So basically, my question is: If you implemented the tab bar as your main navigation: should it be visible at all time or is it possible to have a full screen overlay ('succes confirmation') or a sub-page or so, that hides/covers the tab bar?

-

**Use case**
This app will be used during conferences and presentations to capture the current time. With the time 'bookmarked', users could quickly go back to a moment of a presentation and re-live that piece of information, whether it be a sum-up, an image or a great quote.

To help the user focus on the presentation and doesn't need to know where he/she should tap, the buttons are pretty big and actually the only buttons on the screen, within finger range. If the tab bar would be available, it'll be near those two buttons and might end up in mis-clicking.

I simply want to hide the tab bar so this screen got a complete focus on those two buttons.

-

**'Focus' (sub-) page**
This page primarily consists of two big tap-areas at the bottom. To maintain focus on these two buttons the tab-bar should be hidden, instead of having additional actionable buttons on this particular screen.

[image]

**Confirmation overlay**
On the image below you'll see an example of the confirmation screen. It covers the page you were on with an overlay and the succes confirmation.

[image]

*Feel free to edit this post to make it a bit more specific or understandable :)*

Comment: You can set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to true on your view controller and it will hide the tab bar.

Comment: Ah, if it's as easy as that, that would've been great.

I'm only designing this tho, not programming. But instead of delivering a design to programmers that isn't code able, I want to actually deliver something realistic. My team lead told me it wasn't doable, but apparently it is :)

Comment: Simple present a modal screen on top of rootview . Please use http://stackoverflow.com/a/6683143/1142743